# How to select related in django model so it wont generate a lot of subqueries

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm

I have lot of models that are referring to each other in some way, for example:

Port is referring to City, which in its turn refers to Country. Then in django admin I want to show in list_display Ports country:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()


class City(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)


class Port(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city.county.title
```

So basically for each port django is generating more queries. I assume that `select_related` would help me somehow in this case, but how to use it properly within the model?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a `PortManager` class and override `get_queryset` method and reference it in the model:

```
class PortManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PortManager, self).get_queryset().select_related()


class Port(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    objects = PortManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city.country.title
```

Comment: It is just what I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on Ivan's answer, I came up with the following structure for multiple models related with "one to many" and "many to many" relations using `select_related` and `prefetch_related` accordingly.

In the provided example only `select_related` is required.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(self.title)


class CityManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().select_related('country')


class City(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    objects = CityManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}-{1}'.format(
            self.title,
            self.country.__str__(),
        )


class PortManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().select_related('city')


class Port(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    objects = PortManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city.__str__()
```